# subset whole data frame for value and return rows in which value are found

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to subset a data frame containing 626 obs. of 149 variables and I want to look for a specific string and return the rows that have that value regardless of what column it is found in.

For example:

I am looking for this string "GO:0004674" in a data frame that can contain this string in many different columns and rows as shown below in the image link.

[image]

For example the string "GO:0004674" can be found in row 12, 13 and 14. So I would want to keep only those rows and later on export them.

How can I perform this? All examples that I have seen thus far only look for string in a specific column and not in the whole dataframe.

Ant help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like this should do it : `df[rowSums( sapply(df, grepl,pattern="GO:0004674"))>0,]`

Comment: replace the image by a `dput(head(your_data_frame))`

Comment: Just `df[rowSums(df == 'GO:0004674') > 0,]`

Comment: @HubertL That worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` to do row-wise operation using the argument `MARGIN = 1`. Example:

```
mydf[apply(mydf, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) {"GO:0004674" %in% x}), ]
```

Comment: This returns only a subset of rows from my data frame, 6 to be exact. When I know that this particular string is found in 57 rows in my data frame. This is where i have been stuck on for a while now. I do not understand why when

Comment: Worked fine for me when I reconstructed your sample data - in any case @HubertL's answer worked for you.